# A calculus exercise on prime numbers.

Tags: calculus

I am interested in it because of the $RSA$ algorithm, however I cannot work it out.

Suppose $n = pq$ (In this problem we study the case where $p$ and $q$ $\textbf{no need to be different}$).

Denote $\pi(x) = \{n \in N_+,n \leq x \mid n$ can be factorized into $2$ primes$\}$, for example, $\pi(15) =\{4,6,9,10,14,15\}$. $8 \notin \pi(x)$ (because $8=2^3$,$3$ primes in it), and $21 \notin \pi(x)$, since $21>15$. The power of $\pi(15)$ is $6$. How to evaluate the power of $\pi(x)$?

My trials fail. I pick up a prime $p_i<x$, and attempt to find another prime $q$ such that $p_iq < x$. By prime theorem, for each $p_i$,we can find about $\dfrac{x}{p_i}$ primes that satisfy $p_iq<x$. Then we evaluate the sum:

$S(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{p_i \leq x}\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{p_i}}{\ln\dfrac{x}{p_i}} = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{p_i \leq x} \dfrac{x}{p_i(\ln x-\ln p_i)}$. The $\dfrac{1}{2}$ is because $(p_i,q_i)$ and $(q_i,p_i)$ yields the same element $p_iq_i$ in the set.

If we can get $S(x)$, the numbers used in $RSA$ is about $S(x)-\dfrac{2\sqrt x}{\ln x}$. That's because when we use $RSA$, $p,q$ are distinct and we have to delete some elements in the set $\pi(x)$ when the element is a square of some prime $p$. Since $p^2 \leq x$, we have $p \leq \sqrt{x}$ and then use prime theorem to evaluate $\#\{p$ is a prime, $p \leq \sqrt{x}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such numbers $n=p\cdot q$ are called *semiprimes*. The semiprime counting function, denoted by $\pi^{(2)}(x)$, is given by
$$
 \pi^{(2)}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(\sqrt{x})}\left[\pi\left(\frac{x}{p_k}\right)-k+1\right], 
$$
where $\pi(x)\sim \frac{x}{\log(x)}$ is the usual prime counting function and $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime. For further details and proofs see the references [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiprime.html).